# Target nested tables InDesign script

Tags: javascript, width, adobe-indesign

I am trying to change the width of  a column in this nested table, but it isn't working. What am I doing wrong? It works fine when the table is not nested.

Un-nested works:

```
app.activeDocument.stories.everyItem().tables.everyItem().columns[0].width = "53mm";
```

Nested doesn't work:

```
app.activeDocument.stories.everyItem().tables.everyItem().tables.everyItem().columns[0].width = "53mm";
```

Answer (score 2):

insert `.cells.everyItem().texts[0]` will solve this issue.

try this code

```
app.activeDocument.stories.everyItem().tables.everyItem().cells.everyItem().texts[0].tables.everyItem().columns[0].width = "53mm";
```

Comment: Right! A table is part of `text`, not *table* again.